# How to change a list outside a consumer

Tags: java, list, foreach, consumer

I'm working on a problem for school. A lot of this method was already implemented and I'm not allowed to make too many changes.

Actually I can only make changes in **specific** spots.

Here's the code of the method I'm working on, although some words are in Dutch, it should be readable.

It should read lines of a file, create addresses from the text (which is saved as (street+" "+number+" "+place)) and add them to a list which is returned. The file ends with an empty line.

```
@Override
public List<Adres> query(ISpecification specification) {
    if (specification instanceof FileSpecification) {
        if (((FileSpecification) specification).toFileQuery().equals("ALL")) {
            ArrayList<Adres> adressen = new ArrayList<>();
/*---start of my code*/
            File studentF = new File(fsConnection.getStudentConnection());
            try {
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(studentF);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                br.lines().forEach(new Consumer<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void accept(String line) {
                        String[] words = line.split("\\s");
                        if(words.length == 3){
 /*line i'm having trouble with*/adressen.add(new Adres(words[0], Integer.parseInt(words[1]), words[2]);
                        }
                    } 
                });
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AdresFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);//Don't mind this
            }
/*---end of my code*/
            //System.out.println("query: Nog niet geimplementeerd!");
            return adressen;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you see I wanted to access a list outside of a consumer block. I know now this is not possible. I thought of creating a different method or so, but that is not allowed. I have to use the foreach method. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to make the list `final` : `final ArrayList<Adres> adressen = new ArrayList<>();` .

Comment: But doesn't that make the list immutable?

Comment: No, it only means that you won't be able to later assign another object to the `adressen` variable .

Comment: And just a reminder: chances are small that any other input will show up here; so considering accepting the most helpful answer at some point ...

Answer (score 3):

When you are working with Java7, then the compiler would need

```
final ArrayList<Adres> adressen = new ArrayList<>();
```

there. The point is: you want to use that local variable **within** an anoymous inner class; in other words: in a context that is somehow decoupled from the class you put the source code. And in order for the decoupled class to able to **use** adressen needs to be final (so that the compiler knows: that reference will not change later on). And given your comment: no, this doesn't magically turn an object into something that is **immutable**. It just prevents that the **reference** changes the "target" it is pointing to!

But as you are not allowed to change that line, you could go for:

```
ArrayList<Adres> adressen = new ArrayList<>();
final ArrayList<Adres> tempAdressen = adressen;
```

and then have *your* code use tempAdressen.

Alternatively, I assume you are using Java7. With Java8, the compiler should be able to understand that `adressen` is *effectively final*; and thus it should accept the source code as is.

Comment: I didn't knew that Java 8 was able to recognize that. Well, the good habits are already here but good to know.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are already using Java8, because of the call to `lines()` in BufferedReader.

So my suggestion is to do a map then a collect to list, instead of a forEach. This way you will not need to access the list from within your Consumer.

```
adressen.addAll(
    br.lines().map(line -> {
                    String[] words = line.split("\\s");
                    if (words.length == 3) {
                        return new Adres(words[0], Integer.parseInt(words[1]), words[2]);
                    }
                    return null;
                })
          .filter(Objects::nonNull)
          .collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java8, you can use **java.util.stream.Collectors** to return a list of elements directly from a stream. The use of collectors help you to avoid side effects (in your case, the need to use an external array to put the elements parsed).

I would personally write it using the following lambda:

```
List<Adres> adressen = br.lines().stream()
    .map(line -> line.split("\\s"))
    .filter(words -> words.length == 3)
    .map(words -> new Adres(words[0], Integer.parseInt(words[1]), words[2]))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will work, yet it won't handle the case in which the data is malformed. To solve that problem, one can change the code above to handle if a line is not composed of 3 elements by modifying the lambda (even if this is not very elegant):

```
List<Adres> adressen = br.lines().stream()
    .map(line -> line.split("\\s"))
    .filter(words -> {
         if (words.length == 3)
             return true;
         else {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException();
         }
    })
    .map(words -> new Adres(words[0], Integer.parseInt(words[1]), words[2]))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```